Spring boot 3.2.4 - micrometer - traceid and spanid not printing
I wanted to use micrometer ( as it is recommended over sleuth ) and implemented using
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/3.3/reference/actuator/tracing.html
see Issue -  [contactdetailsservice,,]

2024-04-14T19:03:40.054+01:00 DEBUG 11856 --- [nio-9001-exec-1]
[contactdetailsservice,,]o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        :
Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver

The spring boot app is almost pure out of the  box i.e. no RestTemplateBuilder or WebClient bean ( as this is a standalone small service - not talking with any other)
Code :
Additional dependencies other than web ( no actuator )
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
        <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-zipkin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

application.properties

spring.application.name=contactdetailsservice server.port=9001
logging.level.org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet=DEBUG
management.tracing.sampling.probability=1
logging.pattern.correlation=[${spring.application.name:},%X{traceId:-},%X{spanId:-}]
logging.include-application-name=false

Sample controller code
@GetMapping("/customer/{cid}/contactdetails")
public ContactDetails getCustomerContactDetails(@PathVariable String cid) {

    return details.stream().filter(detail -> cid.equals(detail.contactId())).findAny().orElse(null);

}

I googled  but could not get any solution from this ( but may be there is something that I skipped)
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/1147

This is how I resolved the issue
Step1: Added Actuator dependency.
this started adding trace and span id
I don't have zipkin yet, so one of the service was logging errors.
Step 2: Commented  the dependency **THIS IS TEMPORARY
<dependency>            
    <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>     
    <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-zipkin</artifactId>      
</dependency>

Step 3 : After spinning zipkin, I added / uncommented the Step 2 dependency
This is ok. But there is no correlation as I am creating webclient as
@Bean
WebClient webClient() {
    return WebClient.create();  //INCORRECT
}

After looking at the documentation -
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/3.3/reference/io/rest-client.html#io.rest-client.webclient MyService

I created bean as (using Builder)
@Bean
WebClient webClient(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
    return webClientBuilder.build(); //CORRECT
}

Now there is correlation - traceid
2024-04-14T21:16:04.764+01:00 DEBUG 17880 --- [dvlaservice]
 [nio-9080-exec-1]
 [dvlaservice,90c8edf37db433ff02ca5b4c8f0e0fdc,98b476bebb74a420]o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
 
 
 2024-04-14T21:16:04.745+01:00 DEBUG 15592 --- [vehicledetailsservice]
 [nio-9002-exec-1]
 [vehicledetailsservice,90c8edf37db433ff02ca5b4c8f0e0fdc,21616d998b9ea1d0]o.
 
 2024-04-14T21:16:04.558+01:00 DEBUG 13748 --- [nio-9001-exec-1]
 [contactdetailsservice,90c8edf37db433ff02ca5b4c8f0e0fdc,207b5a67568fe97e]


Thanks @M Deinum I struggled to format (used ctrl + K) answer
